# How to add navigationhistory controls,drag and zoom in & out controls ,etc in openlayer 6?

Tags: openlayers, openlayers-3, openlayers-6

I want to add some controls features which I used in Openlayer2 to ol6. In openlayer2 I used navigationhistory, click & drag zoom in-out buy activating controls.

```
var mouseControl = {'pan':'move','zoom':'crosshair','zoomout':'crosshair','toolQuery':'context-menu', 'mse':'crosshair'};
for(key in controls) {
     control = controls[key];
     // if condition here-based on tool(zoom in/out,pan/navhistory,etc) selected
     control.activate(); //activate based on the tool selected
}
```

how do I do it in ol6

Comment: The default interactions should be sufficient for most cases.  For navigation history see this example https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/permalink.htm

Comment: yes..but the user want to zoom in & out a particular location by click and drag , like in openlayer 2. That control tools are not available in ol6. right ?

Comment: The default interactions include DragZoom https://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/module-ol_interaction_DragZoom-DragZoom.html

Comment: ys..thanks alot @Mike. I got shift+drag zoom, how could I disable shift key ? I just want click & drag zoom., no keys needed. My code is:      var interactions = defaultInteractions({
  shiftDragZoom: false
});
interactions.push(new DragZoom({
  duration: 200,
  condition: platformModifierKeyOnly })); });

Comment: platformModifierKeyOnly is the Windows control key.  For no keys you would need noModifierKeys but as that conflicts with the default for DragPan you would also need to disable or customise DragPan.